# function for set the Subscription price with a shortocde

Tags: woocommerce, subscription, shortcode

i need help please for add a function (in my function.php child theme) for set the Subscription price for a simple subscription product (Woocommerce Subscription) with ID=10 for example, with a shortcode (for example [get_sheet_value location=”DAILY!A3″] ) that i already set with sync Google sheets
i tried many codes already but no one works
thanks

i tried this code, but not working :-(

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'change_and_save_product_price', 10, 2 );

function change_and_save_product_price() {
if ( get_post_type() === "product" ){ // or use: is_product()
    // Regular Price
    $regular_price = 400;

// Sale Price (If you want to add any)
$sale_price = '[get_sheet_value location="DAILY!K3"]';

// Set the product ID of the product you want to change the price of
$productID = 5964;

// Get product
    $product = wc_get_product($productID);

// Set regular price
$product->set_regular_price( $regular_price );

// If your product has a Sale price
if( $sale_price ) {
$product->set_sale_price( $sale_price );
$new_price = $sale_price;
} else {
$new_price = $regular_price;
            }
// Set new price
$product->set_price( $new_price );

// Save to database (Note: You might want to clear cache of your page and then reload, if it   still doesn't show up go to the product page and check there.)
$product->save();
    }
    }
    do_action('get_header');
```